# Would it be wise to start every ES6 javascript file with { and end with } to isolate code

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, scope

Starting every file with **{** and end with **}** would isolate all code in that file in a block, and make every 'let' declared variable private to the file.

Would it be good practice to do so?

Comment: Why do that instead of using modules?

Comment: Modules would be even better since they already isolate your code for you.  Even before ES6, there were modules (like jQuery) that put most or all their code inside an IIFE for this reason.  The concept of isolating a module is a good thing so only what you want to be public is public and there are fewer opportunities for accidental symbol collision.  There are multiple ways to accomplish it depending upon your target execution environment.

Comment: The target execution environment would be the browser. It seems like a nice way to isolate code the "ES6 way", instead of using IIFE. It does achieve the same as IIFE (as long as you use **let** instead of var, and use strict mode) but I don't see anybody doing it. As for modules, that seems an overly complex design pattern for small javascript files executed in the browser. (PS. I have to teach Javascript to front-end developers, and I would like to point students to "modern Javascript" rather than use design patterns of the past)

Comment: "*I would like to point students to "modern Javascript" rather than use design patterns of the past*" we aren't talking about the module *pattern*, we are talking about the [ES6 modules](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules) that have been *designed* to reduce complexity and isolate different pieces of code. Anything declared within a module is within module scope and will not be visible globally. Since browsers support modules, what you have to do specify `<script type="module">` and any script referenced or within will be treated as a module.